# Topic Advertise Conflict: md5sum and Datatype Mismatch

Tags: ros-melodic, ubuntu, mavros, ubuntu-bionic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,
I have been trying to set a GPS position by setting `mavros/setpoint_position/global`, but faced with this error message:

```
 [ERROR] [1628412556.927932932]: Tried to advertise on topic [/mavros/setpoint_position/global] with md5sum [076ded0190b9e045f9c55264659ef102] and datatype [mavros_msgs/GlobalPositionTarget], but the topic is already advertised as md5sum [cc409c8ed6064d8a846fa207bf3fba6b] and datatype [geographic_msgs/GeoPoseStamped]
[ INFO] [1628412557.179607573]: Connected to PX4!
```

What is wrong here?
Based on the [documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/mavros#mavros.2FPlugins.setpoint_position) which seems to be wrong bye the way, I had to use `mavros_msgs/GlobalPositionTarget`
but doing so, results in failure of the application in runtime and instead I'm instructed to use `geographic_msgs/GeoPoseStamped` instead. now that I use this, when I subscribe to `mavros/global_position/global` I get the stated error.

in case it matters, this is my node that sets the gps position:

```
#include <limits>
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/NavSatFix.h>
#include <geographic_msgs/GeoPoseStamped.h>
#include <mavros_msgs/GlobalPositionTarget.h>

//http://wiki.ros.org/mavros
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "offb_node22");
    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    
    //set gps 
    //setpoint_position/global
    ros::Publisher pub_global_gps = nh.advertise<geographic_msgs::GeoPoseStamped>("mavros/setpoint_position/global", 10);
    geographic_msgs::GeoPoseStamped gps_target;

    //the setpoint publishing rate MUST be faster than 2Hz
    ros::Rate rate(20.0);
    
    // wait for GPS connection
    while(ros::ok()) 
    {
        gps_target.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
        gps_target.header.frame_id = "base_link";

        gps_target.pose.position.altitude = 10;
        gps_target.pose.position.latitude = 10;
        gps_target.pose.position.longitude = 10;

        pub_global_gps.publish(gps_target);

        ros::spinOnce();
        rate.sleep();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/384010/tried-to-advertise-on-topic-%5B/mavros/setpoint_position/global%5D-with-md5sum-%5B07...%5D-and-datatype-%5Bmavros_msgs/globalpositiontarget%5D,-but-the-topic-is-already-advertised-as-md5sum-%5Bcc...%5D-and-datatype-%5Bgeographic_msgs/geoposestamped%5D/) by [Rika](https://answers.ros.org/users/75014/rika/) on ROS Answers with karma: 72 on 2021-08-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would do the following checks:

1. Do not run this publisher node. Simply check the message type by `rostopic info mavros/setpoint_position/global`
2. If the message type is correct and matching (e.g. `geographic_msgs/GeoPoseStamped`), and the similar error message persists, then it could be due to the fact that there are 2 different versions of the message type `geographic_msgs/GeoPoseStamped` in your computer. Make sure to have the same version of `geographic_msgs/GeoPoseStamped` to resolve this issue.

---

Originally posted by [Benjamin-Tan](https://answers.ros.org/users/75534/benjamin-tan/) with karma: 56 on 2021-08-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1